# Can ご存じです function as a transitive verb?

Tags: grammar, particle-を

I recently got an automated email from Twitter with the following subject (except with real user names):

> username さん、username さん、username さんをご存じですか?

My question is about `を` paired with `ご存じですか`.  As I understand it, `を` normally marks the direct object of a verb.  Therefore, I expect it to be followed by a transitive verb; if there is no verb, I expect one to be implied.  However, this sentence ends with a noun and copula instead, so I can't make grammatical sense of it.

I assume this phrase *is* grammatical, as I got it in an email that was likely to be proofread, and I can find [plenty of uses online](https://www.google.com/search?hl=ja&q=%22%E3%82%92%E3%81%94%E5%AD%98%E3%81%98%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B%22) on websites that I think are likely to contain standard Japanese.

So how does it work grammatically?  The only explanation I can come up with is that `ご存じです` is functioning as a transitive verb, like a polite/honorific form of `存じる`.  Is there a better explanation?

Comment: 「～～をお持ちです」「～～をお待ちです」「～～をお召し上がりです」「(こちらのお客様は)～～をご希望です。」「～～をご[所望]{しょもう}です。」「～～をご検討(中)ですか？」「～～をご心配ですか？」などもあります～

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ご存じです is an irregular honorific form of the verb 知る. It functions exactly the same with respect to subjects, objects and so on.

More than that, there is a regular honorific form of verbs お+Vi+です (Vi is a -ます stem). For example, お聞きです from the verb 聞く. It also has an internal form noun+copula, but functions as a verb.

It seems like any predicate, be it verb, adjective, or noun+copula, can function like a verb, if there are some logical slots for subjects, objects or modifiers in its meaning,

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to find an eloquent way to answer this topic, but couldn't form anything coherent.  This is what I was going for.